# change vector values for many index ranges efficiently

Tags: r, performance, vector

Imaging I have a long vector

```
vec = 1:1E8
```

and a data frame

```
d = data.frame(pos_start=1:1E7, 
               pos_end=(1:1E7) + sample(1:10, 1E7, replace=TRUE), 
               val=runif(1E7))
```

I want to achive the following goal:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(d)) 
  vec[d[i, 'pos_start']:d[i, 'pos_end']] = d[i, 'val']
```

what could be an efficient way to do that?

Comment: Is your actual case also of this form? I.e., `pos_start` is `1:n` and `pos_end` is `1:n + nonnegative integers`?

Comment: This is just an artificial example such that pos_end is greater than pos_start

Comment: I am asking because in this specific case it is *very* straightforward to do what you want. To be more specific, is `all(diff(sort(d$pos_start)) == 1)` in your actual case? Since it is efficiency what you care about, you should provide more information about the true `vec` and `d` as to exploit that..

Comment: In my actual case, there is no pattern in pos_start or pos_end. But there can be overlap between pos_start[i]:pos_end[i] and pos_start[j]:pos_end[j]. In such a case, the replcement is done sequentially, (i.e., i, i+1,...,j)

Comment: I haven't intensively tested this but using data.table this is finishes almost instantly on my machine `setDT(d) ; test <- data.table(vec)[d, res := val, on = .(vec >= pos_start, vec <= pos_end), by = .EACHI]` (`res` column should have the desired output).

Comment: You have at least two possibilities: 1. find a way to take care of overlapping so that you get the final value for each index; 2. code it in Rcpp.